# saving video from Anylogic run results

Tags: anylogic

I want to save the video from the results of my Anylogic simulation. Could you send me a guide?
I want to send my result for others that they didn't install Anylogic. Also, I want use a video of results in my powerpoint.
THANKS

Answer (score 2):

AnyLogic does not come with video recording. Either, you upload the model to the AnyLogic cloud and let your users play with it themselves.

Or you install a screen-recording software such as the free [ScreenCast-o-Matic](https://screencast-o-matic.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a script to speed up, slow down, jump to a time, zoom, pan, change views etc. during the run.  Then you will need to use screen capture software like snagit, or others to actually capture the video and save it to a file.
With the script you can create a more interesting video if you want to move around and focus on different areas without making a whole bunch of smaller videos that you have to piece together.